# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'facebookTrafficPop'

Tags: php, jquery, object

I have a jQuery Script which is being loaded, but when I load via the PHP I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'facebookTrafficPop'
```

When I looked via Chrome Developer consule, I can see the line that it complaines about which this one:

```
jQuery().facebookTrafficPop({
```

This is the code I have in my PHP is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery().facebookTrafficPop({
        title: '<?php echo $params->get('title', 'Facebook Like Us Popup'); ?>',
        message: '<?php echo $params->get('message', ''); ?>',
        url: '<?php echo $params->get('url', $url); ?>',
        showfaces: <?php echo $params->get('showfaces', '1'); ?>,
        timeout: '<?php echo $params->get('timeout', '60'); ?>',
        delay: '<?php echo $params->get('delay', '0'); ?>',
        closeable: <?php echo $params->get('closeable', '1'); ?>,
        advancedClose: <?php echo $params->get('advancedClose', '1'); ?>,
        wait: '<?php echo $params->get('wait', '0'); ?>',
        //lang: '<?php echo $params->get('lang', 'en'); ?>',
        lang: '<?php echo $lang->getTag(); ?>',
        opacity: '<?php echo $params->get('opacity', '25'); ?>'
    });
});
</script>
```

And This is what I see in chrome:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
//  jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery().facebookTrafficPop({
**Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'facebookTrafficPop'**
        title: 'Facebook Like Us Popup',
        message: '',
        url: 'https://www.facebook.com/Arab.Dentist.Network',
        showfaces: 1,
        timeout: '60',
        delay: '0',
        closeable: 0,
        advancedClose: 0,
        wait: '0',
        //lang: 'en',
        lang: 'en-GB',
        opacity: '25'
    });
});
</script>
```

Please let me know if you can help in solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `()` from the line that causes the error:

```
jQuery.facebookTrafficPop({
```

Edit: You might have to enter a selector inside the parentheses

Comment: if i do what @Trew suggested, that i get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'facebookTrafficPop'

Comment: Do you have some site we can test, or link to where to get the plugin?

Comment: sure, @Trew I have loaded it now here https://innovations-it.com/zoo_demo/en/social-web/facebook-like-us-popup-module

Comment: aah, then the problem is that you are loading your plugin before you are loading jQuery. So move the plugin just below the line you are loading jQuery, and it should work I think

Comment: Hi @Trew i switch the order, now i get this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined ------and another error: Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'facebookTrafficPop'

Comment: Well, you are loading jQuery 3 times on that page, the order is: jQuery, the plugin, jQuery, jQuery. So you should only load it once. And where do you use the plugin? Sorry, it's kind of hard debugging your "encrypted" site.

Comment: That seems true @Terw but we do it using JQ no conflict. This is done because we are using a special extension that renders the back-end on the front end. it is messy, i will keep at it. thanks for all the help.

Comment: using `noConflict` will not help if you load multiple jQuery files. It works against `$` not the `jQuery´ variable.